# SimpleXML parsing elementlist exception

Tags: list, element, simple-framework, unmarshalling

Hi i have problem with parsing this xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <TdlID>202</TdlID>
            <TdlDesc>1234567890</TdlDesc>
            <Due>2013-07-19</Due>
            <Done>0</Done>
            <Creadate>2013-07-08 23:43:51</Creadate>
            <UsrLogin>demouser</UsrLogin>
            <Prj>3211</Prj>
            <Chngdate>2013-07-17</Chngdate>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <TdlID>218</TdlID>
            <TdlDesc>fghjkljh</TdlDesc>
            <Due>2013-07-31</Due>
            <Done>1</Done>
            <Creadate>2013-07-10 11:06:10</Creadate>
            <UsrLogin>demouser</UsrLogin>
            <Prj>abcd</Prj>
            <Chngdate>2013-07-17</Chngdate>
        </Item>
    </Items>
    <Status>
        <code>0</code>
        <message>Its Working!!!</message>
    </Status>
</Response>
```

I know, that problem is on 100% in ElementList, but have no idea, where :(

```
package sk.jbase.todolist.xml;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Order;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Element(name = "Items")
@Order(elements = "Item")
public class Items {

    @ElementList(name = "Item")
    protected List<Item> item;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        if (item == null) {
            item = new ArrayList<Item>();
        }
        return this.item;
    }

}
```

Exception:

```
07-27 21:44:45.070: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.validate(Composite.java:644)
07-27 21:44:45.075: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:449)
07-27 21:44:45.075: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
07-27 21:44:45.075: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
07-27 21:44:45.075: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
07-27 21:44:45.075: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
07-27 21:44:45.075: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
07-27 21:44:45.075: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.populate(CompositeList.java:175)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.read(CompositeList.java:120)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:562)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:499)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): sk.jbase.myproj.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment$1.dataDownloadedSuccessfully(MainActivity.java:188)
07-27 21:44:45.080: E/TEST serializer(16881): task.RequestTask.onPostExecute(RequestTask.java:98)
07-27 21:44:45.085: E/TEST serializer(16881): task.RequestTask.onPostExecute(RequestTask.java:22)
07-27 21:44:45.085: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-27 21:44:45.095: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-27 21:44:45.095: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-27 21:44:45.095: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 21:44:45.095: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 21:44:45.095: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-27 21:44:45.095: E/TEST serializer(16881): java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 21:44:45.095: E/TEST serializer(16881): java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 21:44:45.095: E/TEST serializer(16881): com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-27 21:44:45.095: E/TEST serializer(16881): com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-27 21:44:45.095: E/TEST serializer(16881): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-27 21:44:45.885: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.validate(Composite.java:644)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:449)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.populate(CompositeList.java:175)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.CompositeList.read(CompositeList.java:120)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readVariable(Composite.java:623)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readInstance(Composite.java:573)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readUnion(Composite.java:549)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElement(Composite.java:532)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.readElements(Composite.java:445)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.access$400(Composite.java:59)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite$Builder.read(Composite.java:1383)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:201)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Composite.read(Composite.java:148)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Traverser.read(Traverser.java:92)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:625)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:606)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:584)
07-27 21:44:45.890: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:562)
07-27 21:44:45.895: E/TEST serializer(16881): org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister.read(Persister.java:499)
07-27 21:44:45.895: E/TEST serializer(16881): sk.jbase.myproj.MainActivity$DummySectionFragment$1.dataDownloadedSuccessfully(MainActivity.java:188)
07-27 21:44:45.895: E/TEST serializer(16881): task.RequestTask.onPostExecute(RequestTask.java:98)
07-27 21:44:45.895: E/TEST serializer(16881): task.RequestTask.onPostExecute(RequestTask.java:22)
07-27 21:44:45.895: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
07-27 21:44:45.895: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
07-27 21:44:45.895: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
07-27 21:44:45.895: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-27 21:44:45.910: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-27 21:44:45.910: E/TEST serializer(16881): android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-27 21:44:45.910: E/TEST serializer(16881): java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-27 21:44:45.910: E/TEST serializer(16881): java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-27 21:44:45.910: E/TEST serializer(16881): com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-27 21:44:45.910: E/TEST serializer(16881): com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-27 21:44:45.910: E/TEST serializer(16881): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried without elementlist, but with one Item element, that working, bud with list no.
Can you help me pls?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved :

```
 @ElementList(entry = "Item", inline = true)
    protected List<Item> item;
```