# Simple XML Annotations Issue

Tags: java, android, annotations, retrofit2, simple-framework

I am using Retrofit to parse the response from the server and I am not able to see what annotations should  I use to solve this. I even referred [this](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php).
What should be the right way.

Following is my onFailure log from Retrofit.

failurejava.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ElementException: Element 'route' does not have a match in class drish.com.dsfaallstars.updatefromserver.model.Routes at line -1
        null

The XML I am receiving:

```
<routes>
    <route>
        <id>20</id>
        <name>Barnala</name>
        <update>false</update>
    </route>
    <route>
        <id>15</id>
        <name>Kapurthala</name>
        <update>false</update>
    </route>
    <route>
        <id>14</id>
        <name>Nakodar</name>
        <update>false</update>
    </route>
</routes>

public class Routes {

  @Root
  @ElementList
  private List<Route> routes;
}

@Root(name = "route")
 public class Route{

    @Element(required = false)
    private String id;

    @Element(required = false)
    private String update;

    @Element(required = false)
    private String name;

    public String getId ()
    {
      return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUpdate ()
    {
      return update;
    }

    public void setUpdate (String update)
    {
      this.update = update;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Element(name = "routes")
@Order(elements = "route")
public class Routes {

  @ElementList(entry = "route",inline = true)
  private List<RoutePojo> route;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Routes{" +
        "route=" + route +
        '}';
  }
}



public class RoutePojo{

    @Element(required = false)
    private String id;

    @Element(required = false)
    private String update;

    @Element(required = false)
    private String name;

    public String getId ()
    {
      return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUpdate ()
    {
      return update;
    }

    public void setUpdate (String update)
    {
      this.update = update;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
      return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
      this.name = name;
    }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "RoutePojo{" +
        "id='" + id + '\'' +
        ", update='" + update + '\'' +
        ", name='" + name + '\'' +
        '}';
  }
}
```

Comment: Took help from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17901818/simplexml-parsing-elementlist-exception